# Publish on a Facebook page using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After 30 April 2014, something changed in facebook API, and now the online guide for publish in a facebook page using php doesn't work.

The error are the following:

> (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

I just did the procedure to take the access-token and the code but when i use this:

```
&scope=manage_pages,publish_stream
```

of this URL defines the permissions you will assign to your app, facebook says that `manage_page` is not good after 30 april 2014 .. what i can use for publish in the page / or the alternative to this?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not correct that `manage_pages` no longer works, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-pages I think it's probably the case that the user declined to give that permission to your app.

You can check the current permissions of the respective user like this:

```
GET /me/permissions
```

(see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#checking)

Also have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#handling which describes a scenario on how to handle missing permissions.